# Maven / OSGi: deploying to an OBR which is not the maven repos

Tags: maven, deployment, osgi, maven-bundle-plugin, obr

My maven build installs artifacts locally and requires access to the project's remote maven repository. I don't have write access to that repository - so my builds (containing my changes) are only local so far.

When I build, I would like to deploy the .jar to a remote OBR which I have control over. This is not a full maven repository (eg. Nexus), just a webserver. A repository.xml describing the OBR should be automatically generated and uploaded.

Simply calling the goal "deploy" will try to upload to the project's maven repo, which fails as I don't have write access.

I want:

- build & install locally, getting all dependencies on remote maven repos as required
- upload jars to the OBR
- generate repository.xml OBR description and upload

How should I configure the maven-bundle-plugin? Which goal must I call?